# Support with creating a report in SQL Server Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am new to SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 and need some support in creating a report, if that is ok with you. First things first, I am not great with coding nor with SQL etc, please be patient with me and I will also do my best to learn out of this :)

**OBJECTIVE**

The objective is to generate a report from a SharePoint Calendar to show in a different view compared to the actual calendar.

**CALENDAR VIEW**

The following information are asked to be entered for a new entry:

[New entry in SP Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQXMo.jpg)

**What it should be in the Report**

Now, this is what the report should be displaying, or something close to that.

[what it should be looking like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GklWu.jpg)

The above excel was created manually and my thoughts were to utilise the SP Calendar and somehow create/generate a report and show the relevant data.

**What I have done so far?**

I have created a custom report in SQL Server Report Builder but I am failing to modify the dates to show the WEEK DAY rather than the actual date e.g. instead of 14/12/2016 09:26:00AM I like to show Wednesday.

```
=Fields!Start_Time.Value
```

I added this `=FormatDateTime(Fields!Start_Time.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt")` which modifies the date/time format but unsure how to convert that to the actual day-name of the week.

I am very sorry I am limited to 2 links I can attach otherwise I would show more screenshots to make it more clear.

Comment: yeh if you read through I asked for support and not "do this for me" and I also mentioned that I created the report but need some tweaks such as for the date....don't judge :)

Comment: So you want to turn a SQL date into a weekday? Is that it?

Comment: just updated the info, re-read again! I want this `=Fields!Start_Time.Value` currently showing as the date in 14/12/2016 09:47:15AM and convert to `Wednesday` instead. I was thinkining something like `=FormatDateTime(Fields!Start_Time.Value,"DAY")`

Comment: If that is your question everything above *I have created..* is unneccesary. We don't need the whole story of everything you want to do and why. Just what your stuck on

Comment: Please see my edit. This would make a much better question to the one you asked. Don't write a novel when a paragraph or two will do the same thing

Comment: yeh but the stuff you deleted is to give the reader/helper the idea what I want to achieve and be able to understand my struggle .... instead of deleting everything, you could have said SORRY CANT HELP YOU .... by deleting stuff out of my post, does not help at all!!!

Comment: Fine I'll roll it back, but your wrong....

Comment: if I was right and a clever guy like you, I would not ask for support but would have solved it myself ... but yeah thanks, you are the admin and can do whatever you like.

Comment: just checked it out but that is more the coding side of the SQL whereas the SQL Builder is where you select the functions etc. Sorry hard to explain in words and shame I could not add more screenshots....`a picture is worth a thousand words`

Comment: Is this Vb.Net? Try `Fields!Start_Time.Value.DayOfWeek`

Comment: yes your code converted it to weekdays but I think why it showing some days as duplicate is because same user has got 2 entries on same day but different time.... need to figure that out how to avoid this.

Comment: Again, your question isn't clear. So you don't want a SQL solution, you want a VB.Net solution, but you haven't included this tag or mentioned VB.Net in your question? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Liam, I would not know if its VB.NET or SQL or whatever .. all I know is that I am using the SQL Server Report Builder which is a wizard to pull in the fields etc.

Comment: @Bucki it isn't VB.NET and the answer provided isn't in VB.NET. The tag should be removed really.

Comment: @Jinx88909 thank you. Just my feedback about the -2 they voted on my post. I find this not fair because I tried to elaborate the issue and tried to put it across for you guys to understand what I am trying to do ... instead of just creating a post and ask "how to do this". Anyway, I hoped for a more welcomed theme instead all this shouting about something I wanted to be helped. I got so many other questions to ask about the current Report I am working and stuck on but don't dare to ask cos of this experience :/

Comment: Keep it simple @Bucki. I didn't vote your question down but the most effective questions are to the point, show the relevant code and what you want to achieve. Have a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read over [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It may give a better insight. As stated by Liam you question would have been fine from _I have created_ and anything previous, with a few exceptions, is just noise that we don't often need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be below function may be resolved your prblem

```
 WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Fields!Start_Time.Value))
```

or

```
 WeekdayName(weekday(Fields!Start_Time.Value))
```

Comment: yes, your code works as well :) actually both `=Fields!Start_Time.Value.DayOfWeek` and `=WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Fields!Start_Time.Value))` do show the same results...

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the Text Box with your date field, and open the Text Box Properties. Go to Number, switch it to Custom, and enter `dddd` as the format. This method avoids using extra code in SQL or the expression builder.

[image]

Comment: finally somebody who is using the same software and understands what I am talking about ....